# Something new for me in Windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, direct-attached-storage

what does Direct Attached Storage DAS mean in windows server 2008.

what does it do or can it be useful for a user using a server

any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Direct-attached storage as a computing term is not specific to Windows 2008.

Typically, DAS refers to the hard disks that are physically connected to your server (via SATA, SCSI or SAS).

It is usually considered opposite to 'NAS' which is network-attached storage (storage that the server can access over the network that is typically served by another server -- e.g. FTP, SMB/CIFS, NFS)

Comment: Yeah, funny, how most people always refer to things in their small piece of reference. I just wonder what "Pepper" means in the context of a Pizza. Pepper is Pepper. No, not every technical term is specific to whatever OS you think you know.

Comment: @TomTom :: I did briefly look to see if Microsoft had co-opted another generic term for one of its Roles / Features in the Server Manager, but couldn't find one, so I guessed the OP must just be referring to the common term -- if not, the OP should show where they have seen the feature referenced

Comment: Maybe the OP is referring to the DirectAccess feature?

Comment: @joeqwerty :: It did cross my mind.  `$DEITY` knows what that does, though -- something about allowing access to a LAN without a VPN, or something.